# The mcc command generated program segfaults

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, feyncalc

I am trying to get FormCalc to work with FeynArts, the only problem is that the ReadForm program that is required for FormCalc to work compiles fine but segfaults...

I am using Mathematica 14, should I try and use an older version of Mathematica?
This SegFault is preventing FormCalc from working as Install[path/to/ReadForm] hangs indefinitely. Any suggestions on how to work around this is much appreciated!

Edit: I am on fedora Linux with gcc 12.3.1-1